# Getting "Rule is invalid" when adding "Require status checks to pass before merging" rule

Tags: github, github-actions

On Github I added a new rule for blocking a PR from merging if an action was failed, but I keep getting "Rule is invalid" error.

Please help.

Answer (score 7):

At first, the UI was a little bit confusing for me as well. I assume you did not click the + sign after selecting the check in the input. Adding check is a two-step process:

First, you type and select your checks, then you must click on the `+` to add the checks.
[image]

After pressing the `+` button, the UI should look the following:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

check the "Branch name pattern" is the existing branch !!!

Comment: please mention what you think could be wrong and how to resolve it step by step so that others could also understand how to tackle this issue. one line answers seldom provide adequate explanation.